# How to concatenate in Excel with multiple criteria

Tags: excel, concatenation

I have an Excel spreadsheet with the following columns: A=Date; B=Company; C=Ad Price; D=Ad Type

Because of the way the data must be exported, it creates a line item per Ad type - EXAMPLE:

```
DATE          COMPANY        AD PRICE    AD TYPE
 5/1/17        Company 1      9840        1
 5/1/17        Company 1                  Tablet
 5/1/17        Company 1                  Banner
```

The above example shows a single sale that is split into three lines because the deal included three types of advertisements that we offer.

Is there a way to concatenate Ad Type so that all Ad Types per sale roll up into the first line associated with that Company (i.e. the line with the Ad Price filled in)?

Comment: how do you find if it is a single sale?? based on date and company or just company? rolled up in a single line as in concatenated and seperated by commas?

Comment: Do you happen to have a formula that you've tried yourself, as it's always better to ask having shown what you've done already. My gut feeling is to use a helper column where you gradually build up a string when ad price is empty, then *reset* the string whenever adtype contains something. That or an array formula (which is effectively the same thing as a helper column anyway)

Comment: @GowthamShiva I believe OP is saying each sale has an associated ad price, so if the row contains a value for ad price, then it's the start of a new sale.

Comment: What I mean is [this sort of thing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdRWz.png): To build up the "build up string" check if there's anything in Ad price, if so start the string from scratch, if not, append your Ad type to whatever's abbove you `=IF([@[AD PRICE]]="",E1&", "&[@[AD TYPE]],[@[AD TYPE]])` where this is placed in `E2`. For the output, concat everything in your line if there's an ad 
 price in the row below you, otherwise do nothing. You have to pad out Ad price so it's not blank in the final row (see the linked image)

Comment: Yes! That's correct ^ - values in the Ad Price column indicate a new sale.

I've used the following formula to concatenate similar data in the past:

`=IF(B2=B1,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(J2,K1)),K1,K1&", " & J2),J2)`

The data was setup as follows: B=Company; J=Account Manager; K=helper column where the above formula was input; sorted alphabetically by Company. So the result was a single line of all Account Managers associated with a single Company